# Adding custom container to MEF

Tags: prism, mef

I have the following case using MEF .

I build my solution by many modules, each module exists in a different dll . I use MEF as a choice to compose all my project. 
Its works fine , but sometimes I add for a module a service class say (AppService), this class simply has custom static methods which deal with generic service of this specific module . Now in this method I need some service which allready composed in MEF. The MEF container allready exists in the mail shell program .
How can get reference to the reference I need . if I use [Import] it doesn't work.
Example :

```
public class AppService
{
  [Import]
  public IService MyService {get;set;}

  public static int Calc()
  {
      return MyService.Calc();   //My service is null
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually have a few problems with that code.

1.Have you confirmed that your `AppService` type is being composed? As you are not `[Export]`-ing it, I can't see how that is generated. If you are not grabbing an instance of `AppService` from the container, you have to manually satisfy the imports:

```
var service = new AppService();
container.ComposeParts(service);
```

2.Your class design has a `static` method, where you are trying to access an `instance` property. I'm assuming you're trying that for one of two reasons. Either, you assume the `interface` for `IService` supports static operations (which they can't), or you are calling an extension method that supports the `IService` type, which is failing because the first argument of the suspected extension method is null:

```
public static int Calc(this IService service) 
{
    return service.Calc(); // failing perhaps?
}
```

If it is the latter extension method scenario, it would suggest something similar to 1) where you need to confirm that your `AppService` type is being composed after it is instantiated.

The fact you have a `static` method trying to access an `instance` property would tell me that you probably need to rethink your design anyway, and remove the `static` modifier:

```
public int Calc()
{
    return MyService.Calc();
}
```

But again, your property is public, so is this method of any use at all? *You current example shouldn't even compile, as you are trying to access an instance property from a static method.*